# strtotime giving odd result

Tags: php, strtotime

OK I'm hoping someone can see where I'm going wrong.

```
$date = "2015-02-4";
$schedule = strtotime('+1 month',$date);
```

for some reason this is giving me 2680415 as the result instead of 1425488400 that I want but if I do

```
$date = "2015-02-4";
$schedule = strtotime($date);
```

I get the correct answer i.e. 1422982800.

$date is not really assigned like that, it is the result of a DB query added to the current month and year.

Comment: Look up [`strtotime`](http://www.php.net/strtotime) - do you see the second parameter? The second parameter is `int $now`. An integer. `2015-02-4` is not an integer. `strtotime($date . ' +1 month')` would work better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append the `+1 MONTH` expression to your `$date` in the call to `strtotime`, instead of passing them as a separate parameters.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Bangkok');

$date     = "2015-02-4";
$schedule = strtotime($date);
echo "Original timestamp:  ", $schedule, PHP_EOL;
echo "Original date:       ", date("Y-m-d", $schedule), PHP_EOL;

$schedule = strtotime($date . ' +1 MONTH');
echo "+ 1 month timestamp: ", $schedule, PHP_EOL;
echo "+ 1 month date:      ", date("Y-m-d", $schedule), PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Original timestamp:  1422982800
Original date:       2015-02-04
+ 1 month timestamp: 1425402000
+ 1 month date:      2015-03-04
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, `strtotime` accepts `int` as a second parameter. So the string should be converted to timestamp before processing:

```
$date = "2015-02-4";
$schedule = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime($date));
```

Or use concatenation as shown in @mhall's answer.